# Test facebook/javascript with local host?

Tags: facebook, url, authentication, web

I just created an app in facebook to get appid, but I don't have a real website or so, I need to test it on my localhost, is that possible to leave the 'website url' field blank and test it?

When I try to FB.login from my javascript I keep getting a dialog with this:

> An error occurred. Please try again later.

Is this caused by I don't have a proper URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just write in the website url: *http://localhost* and in *App Domain* put just *localhost*.

That should do the trick.